# How to modify my code in order to list all the tweets that contain the word "grammy"

Tags: python-3.x

i wrote a python program in order to list all the tweets in a Excel file which contains the word "grammy", but it didn't work, and i don't know how to modify it.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're on Unix, you can list the lines with "grammy" by running: `grep grammy MY_SPREADSHEET_NAME`. If you post your Python code we can help you fix that up too. Generally StackOverflow wants users to post code when they ask questions. (Please make sure you post your code as plaintext, not as an image.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Please don't post your code or exception as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's [hard to read](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post. It didn't work isn't a good description of your problem how did it not work, what were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `line` contains a list of strings. You can iterate over each cell value in `line` and search for your keyword as follows:

```
for line in csvdata:
  for cell in line:
    if 'grammy' in cell:
      print('this line contains my word:', line)
```

The problem with your approach is you initialize the counter variable `i`, then increment that variable, but you never reset the value of `i` to zero. If you want to use your approach, you'd need to reset the `i` counter variables to 0 for each line:

```
for line in csvdata:
  i = 0
  t = t + 1
  i = i + 1
  ... [ rest of your code ]
```

If you don't reset `i` for each line, then the first line will increase `i` by 1, and all subsequent lines will just keep increasing the value of `i`. Eventually this will cause the index error that you're wisely catching!

Another problem with this approach is each line only checks a single value for `i`. So for each row, you're only checking a single cell's value. One way around this is to use the for loop approach I list above (`for cell in line`). Another way would be to use a while loop, but if you're new to programming I'd start by mastering the for loop before you move on to while loops.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @drosehunter if this response solved your problem, feel free to click the green checkbox next to the answer--that will tell others on StackOverflow that this particular thread has been resolved, so others won't waste time checking on this question